# pixel value inside imageview coming negative

Tags: android

i tried to display bitmap on imageview.
i want pixel information during touch event but the pixel value is coming out to be negative.
Below is the code :-

```
thumbnail1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail, 0, 0, thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), matrix, true);
 img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail1);

int pixel =((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap().getPixel(x,y);
```

how can i get proper values of pixel , as i am using matrix to display bitmap.

Comment: no comments, no response?

Answer (score 0):

Here **[getPixel(x,y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixel%28int,%20int%29)** returns the **Color** at the specified location.

```
// get pixel color
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

int A = Color.alpha(pixel);
int R = Color.red(pixel);
int G = Color.green(pixel);
int B = Color.blue(pixel);
```

Pixel has value +/- because it contains color codes.

So you are wrongly taking meaning of **getPixel()**. For more info, take a look at my answer [Working with pixels in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237195/working-with-pixels-in-android/16237385#16237385)